# How does a given complexity class change under polynomial reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Suppose we have a complexity class $C$ (say for example $C = DTIME(2^{cn})$). 
Take a language that belongs to $C$: $L \in C$. 
Define an arbitrary polynomial reduction from language $L$ to $L'$. 
To what complexity class does the result language $L'$ belong?

Thoughts: I think it might depend on the model of the computation. Let's assume that the complexity class is $C = DTIME(f(n))$, which is simulated with a Deterministic Turing Machine.  Under a reduction function $h(n)$ of every language in this complexity would be $DTIME(h(f(n)))$, but I'm not sure how to write/prove it formally.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Thanks @D.W.; I added a dew comments and thoughts to the question. What do you think now?

Comment: The precise details of the answer to any question about complexity theory is likely to depend on the model of computation. This is why we fix a computational model in advance. Also, $h(f(n))$ doesn't make sense, since a reduction $h$ is a map from strings to strings, whereas $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Are you sure you got the direction of the reduction right?

Comment: I think I skipped some details. I think I should put it in the context of the computation mode (e.g. the turning machine), apply the reduction on the language, and calculate its computation time. Does it sounds better,  @DavidRicherby?

Comment: @Daniel First, I suggest thinking in the following terms. There's a reduction from $L$ to $L'$ means that one (not necessarily very good) way of deciding $L$ is to translate to $L'$ and decide $L$. Figure out the cost of doing that (the cost of translating, plus the cost of solving the translated instance). Now, you know that the fastest way of solving $L$ is at most $O(2^{cn})$ steps. What, if anything, does that tell you about how efficiently $L'$ can be solved? Would there be a contradiction if, say, you could solve $L'$ really fast, or if it took a really long time?